# StrongARM mini cache - scratchpad?

Tags: arm, cpu-cache

I'm looking at the manuals on a stronrARM10 and they mention a 512-byte 'mini D-cache'. I'm interested to know if cache settings allow this to become a scratchpad? If this is the case, I intend to code the whole thing in assembly language and ARM is a truly great design. I'm sure you Sony PSX and Jaguar programmers know all about the scratchpad. 128 or fewer instructions but a coder will always find a good use.
Anyone else still programming strongARM10 or the derivatives with Intels SIMD instructions.

Comment: I think the mini d cache is just another cache, and can't be directly addressable.    (You can, I imagine, lock lines in the cache, which makes it just about the same thing)

Comment: Thanks - I will test it out. It will be interesting if an instruction can be fetched from that mini D-cache? THAT will be interesting.  It reminds me of the texels on the N64. We learned to use the CPU for music/SFX and leave the graphics engine in the RSP, just draw everything texture by texture. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think instructions can be fetched from the D cache.

Comment: From the description in the SA-1100 datasheet I found, it sounds more like the exact opposite of what you're after - that describes it as a special thing for streaming large data through which you expect to be quickly evicted again, in order to avoid thrashing in the main D-cache. Never touched a StrongARM myself though.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yep, the Developer's Manual for SA-1110 indicates that allocation is controlled by page table entry bits (if "cacheable" is set but "bufferable" is not, then a load miss is allocated to the minicache; both caches are no-write-allocate). In effect, this small 2-way associative cache acts as a non-temporal buffer (not just streaming but any access for which early eviction would not be problematic). It also appears that SA-1110 does not have any means to lock ways or cache lines. One could only use 512 bytes of a uniquely cacheable but not bufferable page to simulate scratchpad.

Comment: Yes, on further reading, I realized that the MMU I realized that the MMU allows areas of memory from 4K to 4Mb can have different cache settings. If you are programming in assembly-language, you could indeed setup a 4K page, of which you only use the bottom 512 bytes. I guess the only way to be certain is to try it. Good for building a 16x16 tile for a video codec.